# Property With Specific Properties

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

I am thinking of making a game (for the mathematicians that study numbers) in which players try to construct a set with certain properties. Which properties satisfy the following:

Formally, every finite set with the property has a finite super-set that satisfies it, and one that does not satisfy it.

Also it should not be frequent. Formally:

If for any set, one element can be added to make it satisfy the property, it is a bad property.

I think I would need at least two such properties. It does not matter which number system you chose (as long as it is common enough.) I can shape the game around it.

Note: I might make cards with different properties on it, and each player is tring to satisfy a different property.

Note 2: Also, with possibly modified requirements, I could make something like [Ghost](http://blog.xkcd.com/2007/12/31/ghost/).

Comment: Nice title. $ $

Comment: I like your idea for the game. I see it having lots of potential.

Comment: It would be sort of like a trivia game. "I play $\pi$. Well I play the ackerman's number. Dudes, my computer just crashed trying to test the property."

Answer (score 1):

That game sound really cool. Have you considered a number theory style of [Mao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mao_%28card_game%29)? But with only number theoretic rules being valid? Of course under the assumption that each card takes on it value and ace,jack,queen,king being $1,11,12,13$ respectively? You could also let the sign of the card change the value of it in some conceiled way.

Or make your own cards with different numbers. The Idea is you need to look at the number theoretic properties of the working numbers and make assumptions from there.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start the list with my favorite property-with-super-set property:

> The product of the set's numbers $+1$ is a prime.

This works because for any $n \in \Bbb N$ there are infinitely many primes $\equiv 1 \bmod n$, a fact that I think isn't loved enough.

Comment: May be too frequent.

Comment: Ok, as I don't know the rules of your game I wasn't sure what "frequent" meant (and frequency also depends on the desired length). However, I didn't actually mean to give the final result to the question, I just wanted to make an example to motivate others to give theirs :). Anyway, I can also motivate myself: (1) sets with >1 elements that can not be partitioned into two disjoint subsets with equal sum (2)  for each element n also $\varphi(n)$ is in the set (3)  no two elements are coprime ... or maybe crawl through OEIS to find something convenient.

Comment: It seems that any number can be added to a set to make it satisfy this property. This would make it to easy to win.